# Ethernet not working

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu and I am having trouble accessing the internet via eth0 (it was working till yesterday). I have gone through the forums and implemented a few suggestions (creating new ethernet, installing compat-wireless etc..) suggested by other users but nothing seems to be working.
ifconfig command output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:ee:7b:2c:21:64  
      inet6 addr: fe80::beee:7bff:fe2c:2164/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:504 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:95552 (95.5 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:3019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3019 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:237206 (237.2 KB)  TX bytes:237206 (237.2 KB)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: The lo interface should have nothing to do with it. But are you sure your wired LAN is connected? I get similar results only after plugging out the cable. Did you try plugging the network cable out and back in, reboot, check your connection with a different computer, OS or a live system on your current machine?

Comment: yes my lan is connected and i did a reboot. that didn't help

Comment: Are other computers able to connect to that network? Can you check whether your machine is able to do that too by booting it from a live-CD or with another system?

Comment: hey! sudo apt-get install lshw and a reboot worked(i found that solution in of the forums). thanks

Comment: Could you please explain that a bit more or provide us the link to where you found it, so that other people with the same issue might profit from your case, please?

Comment: I think in this case reboot worked. He simply has faulty DHCP that does not always give lease.

Comment: @ByteCommander: i think Barafu Albino might be right. i created a   new connection but did not restart making my old ethernet connection still in play .But, after restart i selected new connection. i also followed this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1505697  Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem seems to be solved (see comments) by a simple reboot.

According to Barafu Albino, it looks like the DHCP did not give the device an IP address first, but worked after the restart...

<sub>Please edit this community wiki answer if you can provide additional details about what might have happened or post your own answer. This one is just to remove the question from the unanswered queue.</sub>

Comment: Abhi Ram challapalli: Please accept this answer to remove your question from the unanswered list and mark it as solved!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, your eth0 interface does not have IPv4 address. This most often means that you do not get DHCP lease. This, in turn, usually is because your network has no DHCP (not working, or MAC-filtered). Before you proceed, you should ask network admin if you must use dynamic (DHCP) or static IP, and what the numbers are.